# Fluent API relationships: one to one or zero relationsip

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have two tables `Cargo` and `CargoMovement` as follows:

```
public class Cargo
{       
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CargoID { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public virtual CargoMovement CargoMovement { get; set; }
}

public class CargoMovement
{  
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public DateTime TimeOfTransit { get; set; }
     public int CargoID { get; set; }
     public virtual Cargo Cargo { get; set; }
}
```

Every `Cargo` could have ONE or Zero `CargoMovement`. Every `CargoMovement` WILL have exactly one `Cargo`.

`CargoID` in Cargo table is primary key. `CargoID` column in `CargoMovement` should be the foreign key.

But when I write the following fluent API, the opposite happens.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PisMark3.Models.Cargo.Cargo>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.CargoMovement)
            .WithRequired(cg => cg.Cargo)                 
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

resulting migration:

```
CreateTable(
                "dbo.CargoMovements",
                c => new
                    {
                        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        TimeOfTransit = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        CargoID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Cargoes", t => t.ID)
                .Index(t => t.ID);
```

Which means that when I try to insert

```
insert into dbo."CargoMovements" ("TimeOfTransit","CargoID")
values(NOW(),44)//44 is existing CargoID in Cargo table
```

It gives me an error that there is no id 1 in `dbo.Cargo`  table. (1 being the identity value of `CargoMovement`)

I am looking for Fluent API solution.

Answer (score 1):

For Fluent Api you need to use a parameterless WithMany() call to set the foreignkey as you can see here : [One-to-One Foreign Key Associations](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations)
so the new code would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PisMark3.Models.Cargo.CargoMovement>()
        .HasRequired(cg => cg.Cargo)
        .WithMany()  
        .HasForeignKey(cg => cg.CargoID);
```

For data anotations try adding :

```
[Required, ForeignKey("Cargo")]
```

Above CargoID like this :

```
 public class CargoMovement
    {  
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeOfTransit { get; set; }
        [Required, ForeignKey("Cargo")]
        public int CargoID { get; set; }
        public virtual Cargo Cargo { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I want to do this with fluent api

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it helps

Comment: `.HasForeignKey ` is not  available. The only option in intellisense are `Map` and `WillCascadeOnDelete`

Comment: Took some figuring out but what about now?

Comment: But there could not be multiple Cargomovements for one cargo

Comment: and even with this code it is creating foreign key in cargo table instead of cargomovements

Comment: When using WithMany without parameters it won't be a 1 to many relationship, I know it's not pretty.
Did you test the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188802/discussion-between-joost-96-and-arbaaz).